# Javascript get IMG src from variable. SharePoint Content Search

Tags: javascript, sharepoint

I'm working on a SharePoint 2013 Content Search Web Part. Within the template it pulls a value of an image like so:

```
var cswpiconURL = $getItemValue(ctx, "Announcement Image");
```

This returns (for example) an image:

```
<img alt="" src="https://i4e7sptest.energyplaza.com/Style%20Library/Client/img/2014-09-6-Life-of-Pix-free-stock-photos-sunset-flares-summer-railway-Julien-Sister.jpg" width="498" style="BORDER: 0px solid; ">
```

I'm trying to create a variable beneath cswpiconURL that pulls ONLY the src from the image. This is what I'm using, but it's not working.

```
var cswpiconURL = $getItemValue(ctx, "Announcement Image");
var cswpiconURLsrc = cswpiconURL.src;
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

`cswpiconURLsrc = cswpiconURL[0].getAttribute('src');`

Answer (score 0):

According to the documentation, it appears that you can pass the selector like so:

```
var cswpiconEL =  document.getElementById("_#= cswpiconURL =#_");
```

So you should be able to select the images source this way:

```
var cswpiconURLsrc =  document.getElementById("_#= cswpiconURL =#_").src;
```

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/jj945138.aspx

Comment: I'm really not strong with JavaScript and I'm just hacking away hoping to get my desired solution. Looking at this, my assumption is that "document.getElementById("_#= cswpiconURL =#_").src" is looking for the ID of the image and returning the SRC. The image doesn't have an ID.

Comment: This was from Microsofts documentation using that function as you are. I'd give it go!